# How to include Partials defined in YMF (Assemble.io / Handlebars.js)

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

I use assemble.io to generate some static files for a simple webpage.

Now i would like to define a list of partials in YAML Front Matter that should be included in the generated page.

I want this

```
<div class="slides">
  {{>slide-intro}}
  {{>slide-welcome}}
  {{>slide-goodbye}}
</div>
```

to be replaced by something like this:

```
---
slides:
  - slide-intro
  - slide-welcome
  - slide-goodbye
---
<div class="slides">
  {{#each slides}}
    {{>this}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

So, I want to use the variable content stored in `this`(e.g. `slide-welcome`) to be used as the name of a partial to be included.

I see that using `{{>this}}` is not working, but i have no clue where to look for the solution.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars 3 introduced [Dynamic Partials](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html#dynamic-partials) and you would use them like this:

```
---
slides:
  - slide-intro
  - slide-welcome
  - slide-goodbye
---
<div class="slides">
  {{#each slides}}
    {{> (lookup ../slides @index) }}
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

However, assemble 0.4.x is using Handlebars 1, so switch to [grunt-assemble](https://github.com/assemble/grunt-assemble), which uses Handlebars 3. grunt-assemble is the same code based, it's just been moved to reflect that it's a grunt plugin.

Comment: That was helpful, but I needed to change `{{> (lookup ../ this) }}` to `{{> (lookup ../slides @index)}}`, because your suggestion throwed errors.